# application path to .net core site on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I have two websites on IIS (actually I try to set up it locally on IISExpress)

- WebApp1 - .NET Framework 4.7.2
- WebApp2 - .NET Core 3.1

I would like to point WebApp2 from WebApp1 on path /Test. I configured my applicationhost.config as below:

```
<sites>
    <site name="WebApp1" id="1">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\SomePath\App\WebApp1" />
    </application>
    <application path="/Test" applicationPool="WebApp2 Pool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\SomePath\App\WebApp2" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44364:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55757:localhost" />
    </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="WebApp2" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="WebApp2 AppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\SomePath\App\WebApp2" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55966:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44369:localhost" />
    </bindings>
    </site>
</sites>
```

My web.config for .net core app is setup like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

csproj is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Both WebApp1 and WebApp2 works fine but I would like that requests send to localhost:44364/Test being handled by WebApp2.

I installed Hosting Bundle for IIS, tried different hosting models and combinations of possible working configuration but every time I got some error (404, 500, 502.5 and many others) and don't have any idea how to make it works. Is it somehow possible to configure?

Comment: What does point WebApp2 from WebApp1 on path /Test mean? Do you want to redirect WebApp1 to WebApp2?

Comment: Yes. What I want to receive is that when I send a request to WebApp1 (localhost:port/Test) it's handled by WebApp2. It works if both apps are .net framework but I cant do the same for WebApp2 on .net core

Comment: You can try to use Application Request Routing to achieve this. [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).